# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type - React and Webpack

Tags: javascript, spring, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Even though I have already added the babel loader no matter what It just doesnt read JSX syntax. Please any help will be much appreciated! I already id run npm install on both the present-env as well as preset-react.

Webpack.config.js

I have used the webpack config given by Spring documentation with react as shown below.

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main/js/app.js',
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
      },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
                        plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
              }
        ]
    }
};
```

Home.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavBar from "./navbar";
import Product from "./product";
import css from "./product.css";

const divStyle = {
  display: "flex",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
  flexDirection: "row",
  justifyContent: "flex-start",
  overFlow: "auto",
  whiteSpace: "nowrap"
};

const horizontalScroll = {
  display: "inline-block"
};
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={divStyle}>
        {this.props.products.map(product => (
          <Product
            key={product.id}
            onDelete={this.props.onDelete}
            product={product}
            onIncrement={this.props.onIncrement}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Error :

```
[INFO] ERROR in ./src/main/js/app.js
[INFO] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/main/resources/templates/index.html' in 'E:\alpha\src\main\js'
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/js/app.js 42:12-62
[INFO] 
[INFO] ERROR in /alpha/src/main/js/home.jsx 21:6
[INFO] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:6)
[INFO] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
[INFO] |   render() {
[INFO] |     return (
[INFO] >       <div style={divStyle}>
[INFO] |         {this.props.products.map(product => (
[INFO] |           <Product
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/js/app.js 40:11-49
[INFO] 
[INFO] ERROR in /alpha/src/main/js/navbar.jsx 5:8
[INFO] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:8)
[INFO] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
[INFO] | 
[INFO] | class NavBar extends Component {
[INFO] >   state = {
[INFO] |     cartItems: 0,
[INFO] |     notifications: 0,
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/js/app.js 38:13-53
```

The error says that it cant specifically read JSX. I already have the babel-loader. Im not sure what else im supposed to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can try it explicitly like this:  `test: /\.(js|jsx)$/` instead of `test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),`

Comment: I did! I think it worked im not sure! Now im getting an error about my style loader. Thanks for the help! Ill get back to you if this comes again!